# Does "size_t" make code portable, or just 'more' portable?

Tags: c++, c

I'm struggling to understand the usefulness of the C++ std::size_t data type. I realize that this data type is platform dependent, and is supposedly meant to make code more portable. However, it seems like it doesn't solve all the problems.

Say for example I'm working on a machine that has 32 bit int. Let's say I decide to write a c style function of this machine that just copies the bytes from one object to another. Inside this function, the memcpy function is used to write the data from object2 to object1. I've chosen an arbitrarily large number.

```
void writeBytes(obj *pobj1, obj *pobj2) 
{
    memcpy(pobj1, pobj2, 1048575);
}
```

This code should (hopefully) compile just fine. Because memcpy uses size_t in its declaration, and because size_t on this platform should be 32 bits, the number of 1048575 should work just fine.

But now let's say I decide to port this function over to a machine that 16 bit ints. Now the memcpy function interprets size_t as being of size 16. In this case, 1048575 is exceeds the allowed values for what memcpy was declared for. The code then fails to compile.

So my question: how exactly was size_t useful in this case? How did it make our code more portable?

Comment: You do realize that you aren't allowed to just copy arbitrary numbers of bytes without regard for the sizes of the source and destination buffers?

Comment: Who tell you `memcpy(pobj1, pobj2, 1048575);` will work fine?

Comment: More portable and less portable is all there is. There's no guaranteed-to-work-everywhere-in-exactly-the-same-way level of portability, at least not for any non-trivial program that does anything useful. There's nothing wrong with something that makes your code "just" more portable.

Comment: If you're working on a 16-bit machine, the addressable memory is no more than `65536` bytes.  You wouldn't be able to create two pointers that each point to something `1048575` in size, let alone use `memcpy()` to copy from one to the other.    You will typically get a compilation error if you hardcode that length as you have, since the compiler can recognise that the value exceeds what a `size_t` can represent.

Comment: There is no compilation error for converting larger integers to `size_t`. It is a well-defined operation (the value is adjusted modulo `SIZE_MAX+1`).

Comment: @M.M There may well be a warning, and if like a sensible programmer, you have enabled -werror, that will give you an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` is able to hold the size of the largest object you can create. It is not required to be your platform's largest native integer type.

Given your example, your code would work regardless of the native integer being 16-bit or 32-bit *if* your platform allows 1048575 byte objects. Or the inverse -- if 1048575 doesn't fit in a `size_t`, you never could have created an object that large to `memcpy`.

Comment: So you're saying that before I would run into issues regarding size_t not being large enough, I would get a compiler error stating that the machine doesn't support that size of object?

Comment: `size_t` will *always* be large enough. Anything outside of its range was literally not possible to `memcpy`. You would get a compiler error for an integer literal that is too large.

Comment: @CoryNelson there is no error for integer literals that are larger than `size_t`, but small enough to fit in some other integer type

Comment: @M.M whoops, you're correct, you'd get a warning at most.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is susceptible to the same overflow and underflow rules as any other integral type.  It's only typedef of an unsigned integral.  Its purpose is not to prevent you from assigning or casting values that are outside of its range.  It defines a standard type that will:

> "store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type
>   (including array)."

If you care about that maximum size, use

```
std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()
```

and make decisions off of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think `size_t` makes (not only your) code more readable and consistent, not necessarily more portable.
It will *help* porting it, however.

Imagine functions working with some size use a happy mixture of `int`, `short`, `long`, `unsigned`, `unsigned short`, ...

When one such function dealing with a size calls another that needs a size parameter too, it's very helpful when one `size_t` fits all (or at least most, like for the result of `read()`).